# Residual finiteness of semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}^2\ltimes \mathbb{Z}[1/10]$ of abelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}[1/10]$ be an abelian group by addition. Let $\mathbb{Z}^2$ act on it by automorphisms by $x\mapsto 2x$ and $x\mapsto 5x$. Is the corresponding semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}^2\ltimes \mathbb{Z}[1/10]$ residually finite?

Comment: Yes, every f.g. metabelian group is residually finite (and such a particular case is easy to deal by hand — i.e. finite quotients are easy to construct).

Comment: Is there any importance of the numbers 2 and 5? I'm curious to know how they arose.

Comment: Exercise: embed this into the profinite group $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}_3)$.